# Magento observer goes in endless loop

Tags: magento

Thanks in advance

I have created one observer i need to set the attribute values on fly using the observer please check the following config and the observer files when i click on the save button the observer goes into the endless . i just want to set the attribute value using this observer

```
<catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <zaptech_save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>upload/observer_product</class>
                        <method>saveTabData</method>
                    </zaptech_save_product_data>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
```

and my observer handler code is here please check

```
 public function saveTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    { 

        $productModel=Mage::registry('current_product')                
                      ->setTestid('1')
                      ->setTestname('Jitendra')
                      ->save();

    }
```

the problem with this code is that the observe goes in endless loop

please help

Thanks again,

Jitendra Dhobi.

Here is the answe of my own question i replaced the event name from catalog_product_save_after to catalog_product_save_before..

```
<catalog_product_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <zaptech_save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>upload/observer_product</class>
                        <method>saveTabData</method>
                    </zaptech_save_product_data>
                </observers>
</catalog_product_save_before>
```

and also remove the save() method from the observer file same below

```
public function saveTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        { 

            $productModel=Mage::registry('current_product');                
            $productModel->setTestid('1');
            $productModel->setTestname('Jitendra');


        }
```

cheers!!!...

Comment: The fact that you are saving the product inside the event triggered after the save is what is causing the loop. Perhaps you could save the attribute only if it is not already set. If it is set, then don't save it again.

Comment: its not set already i set it when the event take place

Comment: Yes, I get that. Where you are setting the attribute, put a condition around it `if (attribute not already set) { set attribute and save} else { do nothing }`. The fact that you are calling $productModel->save() inside your event is probably what is causing your infinite loop. Given that the save method will fire your event again, which saves it again, which ... ad infinitum

Comment: Thanks arun i did it slightly different way i just change the config.xml i am posting the answer here thanks for your comments..

Comment: You should answer your question properly and mark it as 'answered' as this is a useful answer for people to find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a registry to determinate your custom product save and prevent loop.

```
public function saveTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if(Mage::registry('customUpdate')) return;
    Mage::register('customUpdate', true);

    $productModel=Mage::registry('current_product')
        ->setTestid('1')
        ->setTestname('Jitendra')
        ->save();

}
```