# Prevent the trigger of observer in Magento

Tags: php, magento, observers

I think this is a really easy question but given my level in programming it's not that easy for me.

I wonder if there is a way of stopping or don't trigger an observer after some event ocurrs, this is because the observer that I am doing is in an infinite loop and I want to stop it from doing that loop.

I hope it's my question is clearly enough.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
An example could be:
The observer is trigger in the event: core_config_data_save_after and when this observer is started you want to update a value in the core_config_data table, but when you save it the observer is started again and there is the loop

Comment: WHat kind of event and observer are you talking about, in what context? Can you make an example?

Comment: @Pekka the observer is trigger in the event: core_config_data_save_after and suppose that when this observer is started you want to update a value in the core_config_data table, but when you save it the observer is started again and there is the loop

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, I'm assuming run some custom code that also makes changes to `core_config_data table` upon completion?

Comment: @B00MER that's right, I have tried changing the event to <core_config_data_save_before> instead of <core_config_data_save_after> and commented the line where I save to the core_config_data table but I don't know why it didn't save or how to add it to the object that saves to the database. I followed this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204374/magento-observer-goes-in-endless-loop-solved) thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use the registry and set a flag - you simply return from your observer should the registry flag be set on any future hits.

i.e.

```
public function myObserver(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (Mage::registry('my_observer_has_run')) {
        return $this;
    }

    .... Your Code Here ....

    Mage::register('my_observer_has_run', true);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Drew I though that way to do it but in some times I need to run it twice, because sometimes it gets saved the first time and then it gets updated. So sometimes it needs to get run twice. But I think I can figure it out, if you have another idea that can be helpful. Thanks

Comment: So, exactly what condition do you check in order to know to run your code once, twice etc?  Is there an attribute value on your model that you check for?

Comment: I have a question with the Mage::resgister and I hope you can answer this, if I create some registry like your example, if this registry already exist Magento throws an exception or something like that?

Comment: Yes, unless you pass a boolean true value in as the third parameter.  So if you dont want it to throw an exception if the value already exists then call like this: Mage::register('my_observer_has_run', true, true);

Comment: ok, I will try that. Another question, how long does the registry lasts?

Comment: I think I don't need this anymore: `if (Mage::registry('message')) {
                Mage::unregister('message');
                Mage::register('message', $message);
            } else {
                Mage::register('message', $message);
            }`
Right @Drew?

Comment: @apz2000 - You would still require this code if you wish to change the value.  The boolean value I mentioned previously simply allows Mage::register to fail silently (i.e. not throw an exception) should the registry key already exist.  It does NOT allow for the value to be overwritten.  Have a look in app/Mage.php (around line 216) as to how these methods work.

Comment: @apz2000 - Registry values last per request

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12125/discussion-between-apz2000-and-drew)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to locate the observer your wanting and set `<type>disabled</type>`

```
<frontend>
<events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <log>
                    <class>log/visitor</class>
                    <method>initByRequest</method>
                </log>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        .... other events
    </events>
```

locally modified XML to disable the above found observer:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers><log><type>disabled</type></log></observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Code and and more details:

- http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-disable-magento-event/

Comment: I don't want to disable it like this, I want the event dispatched at least once. Can you read my question again? I have updated it.